# could I check through my view state of checkbox from db

Tags: django

My problem is next: I have device table with some params, one of them is device_able, if it is 'enable' I will do something with it. I added two actions to admin actions that change state of device_able on True or False and it works, but when I open any device from table my checkbox is always checked even if it False. I understood that I  don't check data from db about state of checkbox but how to do it? I must use template but I do not understand how to connect my template that checks state of checkbox from db to my admin view of Dev app. Could you give me some useful links for exploring? Or I could check state in my admin.py file?

in my models.py

```
class Dev(models.Model):
    #some params for device
    device_able = models.BooleanField(default=False, choices=((True, 'enable'), (False, 'disable')))
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.device_model
```

in admin.py

```
class DevAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):    
    class Meta:
        widgets = {
            'device_able': forms.CheckboxInput
        }
```

full code of my admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from dev.models import Dev
from django import forms

def make_enable(self, request, queryset):
    queryset.update(device_able=True)
make_enable.short_description = "Mark selected devices as enable"   
def make_disable(self, request, queryset):
    queryset.update(device_able=False)
make_disable.short_description = "Mark selected devices as disable"

class DevAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        widgets = {
            'device_able': forms.CheckboxInput
        }


class DevAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin): 
    fields = ['device_model', 'resolution', 'assets_format', 'scale_factor', 'device_able']
    list_display = ('device_model', 'resolution', 'assets_format', 'scale_factor', 'device_able')
    search_fields = ['device_model']
    actions = [make_enable, make_disable]
    form = DevAdminForm

class DevInline(admin.SimpleListFilter):
    model = Dev

admin.site.register(Dev, DevAdmin)
```

Comment: steppo, thank you for your answer, I've done that, my problem is when I go into any device where keeps its params, the last one is checkbox for 'device_able' and it's always checked even when  'device_able' = False. In my logic I want if 'device_able' = False, checkbox is unchecked

Comment: I use sqlite db, and 'device_able' data type is Boolean(0) but I do not think that is a problem why checkbox in device table is always checked. I'm totally sure that checkbox does not anything from db, because when I create new device in a table it is unchecked by default with that code: 

device_able = models.BooleanField(default=False, choices=((True, 'enable'), (False, 'disable')))

Comment: a problem was in cast of data type. In database I had a column with type String, when I should have a column with type Boolean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution for my problem. First of all, django is so cool that does all work for you. When I created my model I've set 'device_able' as models.CharField. It created in db field with type varchar. After that I've changed in my model 'device_able' to models.BooleanField and changed directly in db type of 'device_able' field on 'bool'. But my checkbox was always checked because only empty string returns False. when I created new project with with the same code, I mean device_able = models.BooleanField, my checkbox start to work correctly!

Answer (score 1):

If you're on the admin view you should use the AdminModel class from the admin module to have your model bound to the form. If you use a ModelForm you must supply the model it is bound to.

That said, in your cse the only need to subclass the AdminModle for your model is to insert tha admin actions, BooleanField are represented by CheckboxInput by default.

I would try in your admin.py:

```
class DevAdmin(admin.AdminModel): 


    def make_device_able()
    ...

    actions = [make_device_able]
```

And register the the class with:

```
admin.site.register(Dev, DevAdmin)
```

Hope it helps.